# Filtering jquery option based on value

Tags: jquery

I have two drop down lists like so

```
            <select required="required" name="firstselection" id="firstselection">
                <option value='0' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Please Choose</option>
                <option value="1">Hello</option>
                <option value="2">Goodbye</option>
            </select>

            <select required="required" name="secondselection" id="secondselection">
                <option value='0' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Please Choose</option>
                <option value='1'>Hi</option>
                <option value='1'>G'day</option>
                <option value='2'>Cya</option>
                <option value='2'>Later</option>
            </select>
```

I'm trying to get it so that if the option of Hello is selected, only the options in the second drop down with value of 1 are shown.

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
                var firstselection = $('#firstselection').val();
                if(firstselection == 1){
                    $('#secondselection option').filter("[value='2']");
                };
            });
```

I have not been able to get the filter to work. I can get it to work if I use remove but I do not wish to remove it.

Comment: I wrote an answer but I had misread the question.  Seeing if I get what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `remove` the `filter`ed elements:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var firstselection = $('#firstselection').val();
    if (firstselection == 1) {
        $('#secondselection option').filter("[value='2']").remove();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N8TEu/

---

If you want to show the options again, use the following:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var firstselection = this.value;
    if (firstselection == 1) {
        $('#secondselection option[value="2"]').hide();
    }
    else if (firstselection == 2) {
        $('#secondselection option[value="2"]').show();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N8TEu/2/

Also note that you don't need the extra step of `.filter()`. You can specify `[value="2"]` right in the selector.

Comment: Just had an ah ha moment thanks to your answer! I had a misunderstanding of how .remove worked. Thank you for this! I will mark it as accepted as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var $opts = $('#secondselection option:not([value="1"]):not(:disabled)');
$('#firstselection').on('change', function(){
    $opts.toggle(this.value != 1);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/37xFF/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('select#firstselection').on('change', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == '1') {
      $('select#secondselection option[value!=1]').hide();
    } else {
      $('select#secondselection option:not(:disabled)').show();
    }
});
```